# Error in webpack encore build error: Module build failed: Unclosed block

Tags: css, symfony, webpack, sass, yarnpkg

I get an error when building my `webpack` using encore in `symfony`.

I've tried various time removing node_modules. and reinstall with yarn install.
But can't find the solution.
It has been working before, but I think after update, it broke.
When I uncomment the bootstrap line everything builds.

> global.scss

```
// customize some Bootstrap variables
$primary: darken(#49a94a, 10%);

// the ~ allows you to reference things in node_modules
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';
```

> yarn encore dev

```
Running webpack ...

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                                                                                       23:05:40

 error  in ./assets/css/global.scss

Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: Unclosed block (229:4)

  227 | 
  228 | svg {
> 229 |   overflow: hidden;
      |    ^
  230 |   vertical-align: middle;
  231 | }
  232 | 

    at /home/user/Web/kcl_symfony4/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:195:19
    at /home/user/Web/kcl_symfony4/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /home/user/Web/kcl_symfony4/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (/home/user/Web/kcl_symfony4/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/Web/kcl_symfony4/node_modules/css-loader/lib/loader.js:31:18)
    at /home/user/Web/kcl_symfony4/node_modules/css-loader/lib/processCss.js:222:4

 error  in ./assets/css/global.scss

Module build failed: Unclosed block (229:4)

  227 | 
  228 | svg {
> 229 |   overflow: hidden;
      |    ^
  230 |   vertical-align: middle;
  231 | }
  232 | 


 @ ./assets/css/global.scss 4:14-199
 @ ./assets/js/app.js

error Command failed with exit code 2.
```

I've tried with building Bootstrap scss standalone and that works. That why I think something is wrong with node_modules.

Comment: Have you tried using an older version of Bootstrap?

Comment: Yes I have, various versions. 4.2 and 4.1 all give the same error.

Comment: Problem fixed by updating @symfony/webpack-encore. Found solution here: https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/issues/287

Comment: You have unclosed block in `./assets/css/global.scss`, try to just empty the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed by updating @symfony/webpack-encore to most current version in the package.json file. After running "yarn upgrade" it worked.